# How i can handle an error in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

i m having a problem with the package.json. This is a cloned project,and and i revised the commas and they are ok. so i don't know where is the mistake.
This is what the terminal says:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Emege\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Emege\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-22T03_04_56_980Z-debug.log.
```

I read this article, but it didn't help me https://dev.to/redslug/7-solutions-to-ejsonparse-or-unexpected-token-npm-install-error-20nh.

```
And this is the package.json


  {
      "name": "tvpassport",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Autentificacion de usuarios",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Jean Mariños",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
        "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
        "connect-redis": "^3.0.1",
        "express": "^4.13.3",
        "express-session": "^1.12.1",
        "mongoose": "^4.2.5",
        "passport": "^0.3.2",
        "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "swig": "^1.4.2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Apart from the commas, the quotes can also impose problems sometimes. Have you made sure that there is no mistake in quotations? Like, while copying from MS word, different ASCII characters are copied

Answer (score 0):

You need only this in you package.json file:

```
{
      "name": "tvpassport",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Autentificacion de usuarios",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Jean Mariños",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
        "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
        "connect-redis": "^3.0.1",
        "express": "^4.13.3",
        "express-session": "^1.12.1",
        "mongoose": "^4.2.5",
        "passport": "^0.3.2",
        "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "swig": "^1.4.2"
      }
    }
```

remove this: ````````

Comment: I don't think that's actually in the OP's ``package.json``. Instead, it's probably just a formatting mistake.

Comment: hi, i m just a student,so what kind of formatting mistakes could be?